# row-broadcasting and transposed vectors?

Tags: scala-breeze

I'm trying to add a row vector to each row of a matrix:

```
val M = DenseMatrix((1.0,2.0,3.0),
                    (4.0,5.0,6.0))

val row = DenseVector(3.0,4.0,5.0).t

val result = M(*,::) + row
// error: could not find implicit value for parameter 
// op: OpAdd.Impl2[
//   BroadcastedRows[DenseMatrix[Double],DenseVector[Double]],
//   Transpose[DenseVector[Double]],
//   That
// ]
```

I can use column vectors instead, but it seems a little convoluted:

```
val result = (M.t(::,*) + row.t).t

// result: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double] =
// 4.0  6.0  8.0
// 7.0  9.0  11.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: please open a bug on github

Comment: @dlwh Ok https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues/450 thanks